# Checking pipeline status stuck

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

I had a self hosted gitlab and i'm trying to add a pipeline for my dev branch but i can't find what's causing the Checking pipeline status stuck.
The best part is that when i try on master branch, it's all working.

Here a simple config test i try to making work :

```
deploy_dev:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: dev
    url: https://dev.jeconsommeberrois.fr
  script:
    - echo 'test'
  only:
    - dev
```

Thanks for your help

Trying to make the pipeline work on dev branch

Comment: Please share your runners configuration. Maybe you have limited your runners to the master branch?